# Find $b_m$ in the Euler Maclaurin summation

Tags: numerical-methods

Find a formula for $b_m$ by evaluating both sides for $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ where $\lambda$ is a parameter. The formula is $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=1/2(f(0)+f(1))+\sum_{m=1}^\inf b_m(f^{(2m-1)}(1)-f^{(2m-1)}(0))$ for some unknown constants $b_m$ independent of f.

I plug in  $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ and get that $\sum_{m=1}^\inf b_m=(2e^\lambda -2-\lambda e^\lambda-\lambda)/2\lambda e^\lambda$. I don't know how to get rid of the sum. Any thought?

Comment: Are you sure you compute well the (2m-1)th derivative of $e^{\lambda x}$ with respect to $x$ ? In your computations, one should find  terms with coefficients $\lambda^{2m-1}$... In this way, the $b_n$ cannot be isolated..

Comment: I substitute x with 1first, then I get $e^\lambda$. Then take (2m-1)th derivative of it, which is still $e^\lambda$?

Comment: no for example, the derivative of $e^{\lambda x}$ with respect to $x$ is $\lambda e^{\lambda x}$, if it is the second derivative, it is $\lambda^2e^{\lambda x}
$, etc...

Comment: Oh I should substitute x with 1 after I get the formula for its (2m-1)th derivative? And the answer should be $\lambda ^ {2m-1}e^\lambda$?

Comment: And $\int_0^1 e^{\lambda x}dx=(e^\lambda -1)/\lambda $?

Comment: That's it ! (see my answer)

Comment: Hi, still I can't find a specific pattern for $b_m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{1}{\lambda}(e^{\lambda}-1)=\dfrac{1}{2}(e^{\lambda}+1)+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}b_m\lambda^{2m-1}(e^{\lambda}-1)$$

Dividing both sides by $(e^{\lambda}-1)$, we obtain:

$$\dfrac{1}{\lambda}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{e^{\lambda}+1}{e^{\lambda}-1}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}b_m\lambda^{2m-1}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{\lambda}=\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{e^{\lambda}-1}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}b_m\lambda^{2m-1}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{e^{\lambda}-1}=\dfrac{1}{\lambda}-\dfrac{1}{2}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}b_m\lambda^{2m-1}$$

Then, multiplying by $\lambda$:

$$\dfrac{\lambda}{e^{\lambda}-1}=1-\dfrac{\lambda}{2}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}b_m\lambda^{2m}$$

Thus the $b_m$ are, up to the sign, the coefficients of the Taylor series of the function on the left hand side.

They are closely related to the Bernoulli numbers. see the part "generating functions" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number

Comment: I see!! Thanks!!

Comment: Something that I have not said is that function $f(\lambda)=\dfrac{\lambda}{e^{\lambda}-1}$ has an apparent discontinuity in $\lambda=0$, but one "forces" $f(0)=1$: this function is $C^{\infty}$ everywhere.

Comment: I got a problem here: the first few terms of the Bernoulli numbers are 1 and -1/2, I can't get rid of the $\lambda /2$. And after simplifying both sides, I got $\sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m \lambda^{2m}=1/2-\lambda /2- \sum_{m=2}^\infty B_m \lambda^m/m!$, where $B_m$ stands for Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: I tried to pull out $b_1\lambda^2$ for m=1, but it seems like that wouldn't help at all.

Comment: In fact, the first 2 Bernoulli numbers are exceptional. But are you supposed to make the connexion with Bernoulli numbers ?

Comment: I am supposed to find a formula fofr $b_m$, so I tried to connect it with Bernoulli numbers, to see if I can find any pattern.